# Make Jest toBeCalledWith treat `undefined` like no argument

Tags: javascript, jestjs, undefined

I recently made a change to some code of this form:

Before:

```
func(a);
```

After:

```
func(a, undefined);
```

A bunch of tests that expect `func` to get called with just `a` are now failing because of the "extra argument".

As far as I'm concerned, there's no breakage here. Although technically the behaviour has changed, it is a very minor change that would rarely show up anywhere.

Is there a way to get Jest to treat extra `undefined` arguments is if they weren't there? Or a better way to handle this situation?

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, `func(a, undefined);` is specifically checking that it's being called with "a" as well as "undefined". Are you able to do something like.... `const args = [a, undefined].filter(Boolean); func(...args);`?

Comment: I think that'd be unsafe, because in the actual code it's more like `func(a, b, c, undefined)`, and stripping out an undefined `b` would be bad. Although they should never be undefined, in this case...